# Is there anyway to limit the number of languages for a component?

Tags: weblate

In Weblate, we have a project with several components underneath it. I understand we can disable the addition of new languages in the component settings, but is there a way to restrict languages for a component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [billing module](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/optionals.html#billing) to enforce such limits on projects.